# How can I integrate GitVersion into TeamCity when building .NET Core projects inside a Docker Container?

Tags: docker, teamcity, gitversion

I have several .NET Core builds running on an Ubuntu Linux agent in TeamCity. The builds actually take place in a Docker container which uses the official Microsoft .NET Core SDK image for Linux.

I have 3 build steps, all of which essentially use the dotnet CLI commands within the docker container:

1. dotnet restore
2. dotnet build
3. dotnet test

The build works great - the assemblies get versioned correctly per GitVersion, the tests run, I get code coverage data via dotCover, etc.

The one thing that doesn't work is that I can't find a way to set my build number based on GitVersion. I believe this is because GitVersion is running inside the container and therefore it is not aware of the TeamCity agent, nor the agent of GitVersion.

So that's my challenge. Remember, this is running under Linux so I can't use an Windows specific tricks. So how do I get GitVersion to somehow "publish" the build number out of the docker container and back into TeamCity?

Comment: This should help - https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/input/docs/build-server-support/build-server/teamcity/

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal It's been a while since I tried to make it work but I believe I did try the meta-runner only to discover it doesn't work on Linux. Have you been able to get it to work?